# Connecting laravel voyager to an existing table

Tags: laravel, voyager

Does anyone know how to connect voyager to an existing table?

If the table doesn't exits one would go to Database=>Create and specify a name and columns and create a table which would display at the tables list but what do we do when there is a table?

I tried just filling the form and clicked the "Create new table" button and received "table already exists" error which was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is already present in the same database as of your laravel project. Then it should be displayed in your list of tables under the **Voyager->Databases**

For ex : In the below snapshot, there was a table **'testtbl'** which was already created by me. So it is getting reflected in the **"Voyager => Databases"**

[image: Test Table]